# Wifi UDP Broadcasting on Verizon Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have Espressif ESP32 modules properly broadcasting Wifi UDP packets to all the nodes (255.255.255.255) connected to either the mobile hotspot on my Verizon smartphone or a TP-LINK Nano router TL-WR802N.  With my Verizon Fios Quantum Gateway G1100 Router, however, broadcast datagrams are not received by nodes on the 2.4GHz guest network.

I've seen recommendation to turn off Client Isolation in similar circumstances, but can only find the IGMP router setting shown here

[image: igmp on verizon router]

So, might turning off IGMP fix my issue or is "isolation" (or another hidden setting) what I need?  Any help towards greater understanding is much appreciated.